# Rails Threadsafe Database Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety

I'm trying to determine if the below would be considered thread safe code.

My model `session_detail` has four columns a `cost` field, a `room_fee` field, and a `tip` field (as a percentages), and a `total_cost` field.

The  `cost` fee, `room` fee are both static. The `tip` field is either blank or a value that doesn't change. The `total_cost` field is always recalculated after being saved.

Is this thread safe? Should this be moved into its own instance method and called on an object? Should it be changed to before save?

```
class SessionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
after_save :update_cost

def update_cost
 total_cost = self.room_fee.to_f + (self.cost.to_f * (1 + self.tip.to_f))
 self.update_attribute(:total_cost, total_cost.round(2))
end
```

Comment: What's the scenario you are worried about?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm trying to learn about race conditions and thread safety, and was worrying about a situation where one thread was writing to the `cost` or `room` fee columns, and another was trying to set the `total_cost` column. So the two columns would end up not equaling `total_cost` because it was combining two different states. Unlikely but just a thought.